# p5.js with dom library increment score button

Tags: p5.js

I would have thought this would have been quite simple but I'm obviously doing something very wrong as score is not incrementing

```
var button;
var paragraph;
var score = 0
function incrementScore() {
score++
}
function setup() {

  createCanvas(100, 100);
  background(0);
  button = createButton('click me');
  button.position(19, 19);
  paragraph = createP(score)
  button.mousePressed(incrementScore);

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your're doing everything right, but you're not updating the text in the canvas: you need to call the `update` function and re-draw the text:

```
function update() {
  background(0);
  paragraph.html(score);
}
```

Comment: The function is called `draw()`, not `update()`